# How to build hisatgenotype extra index files (.link, .locus, etc)

Tags: genotyping

I'm trying to run `hisatgenotype` on a custom genome, originally specified in fasta format. I'm able to use `hisat2-build` to build the `.1.ht2`, ....`.8.ht2` files, however I've not been able to figure out how to get the other files that `hisatgenotype` requires. I've looked into `hisatgenotype_toolkit build-genome` but it errors out due to problems with argument parsing. Is this even possible, or do I have to use the genomes/indices downloaded by the `setup.sh` script?

edit:
The error I get is the same as this issue: https://github.com/DaehwanKimLab/hisat-genotype/issues/69

```
% hisatgenotype_toolkit build-genome --base hla
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ted/miniforge-x86/envs/hisat/hisat-genotype/hisatgenotype_tools/hisatgenotype_build_genome.py", line 546, in <module>
    typing_common.clone_hisatgenotype_database()
  File "/Users/ted/miniforge-x86/envs/hisat/hisat-genotype/hisatgenotype_modules/hisatgenotype_typing_common.py", line 52, in wrapper
    func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: clone_hisatgenotype_database() missing 1 required positional argument: 'destination'
Script exited with error 1
```

If you try to run with an extra positional argument it fails too

```
% hisatgenotype_toolkit build-genome --base hla indices
usage: hisatgenotype_build_genome.py [-h] [--base BASE_FNAME]
                                     [--locus-list LOCUS_LIST]
                                     [--inter-gap INTER_GAP]
                                     [--intra-gap INTRA_GAP]
                                     [--aligner ALIGNER] [--linear-index]
                                     [--commonvar] [--clinvar] [-p THREADS]
                                     [-v]
hisatgenotype_build_genome.py: error: unrecognized arguments: indices
Script exited with error 2
```

And similar problems if you add `--destination indices`

Comment: "but it errors out due to problems with argument passing" - show us your exact command and the error being displayed.